# SQL query to calculate totals

Tags: sql

I'm quite new to SQL querying so please go easy on me if what I've done so far is really odd :)

I have two tables - A for Income and B for Expenditure:

```
Business_ID Income_Desc Income_Amount
1           Income A    1000
1           Income B    3000
1           Income C    2000

Business_ID Expen_Amount
1           2500
```

I'd like to produce a table that shows each of the income amounts, the one expenditure amount, the total income, the total expenditure and a Grand Total of total income-total expenditure.

Something like this if possible

```
Business_ID Income Description  Income Amount   Expenditure Amount  Total
1           Income A            1000            2500                 -
1           Income B            3000            -                    -
1           Income C            2000            -                    -
1           All Amounts         6000            2500                  3500
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
SELECT a. Business_ID, COALESCE (a.Income_Desc, 'All Amounts') AS 'Income Description', SUM(a.Income_Amount) AS 'Income Amount', SUM(b.Expen_Amount) AS Expenditure Amount', (sum(a.Income_Amount)-SUM(b.Expen_Amount)) AS 'Total'
FROM Income AS a LEFT JOIN Expenditure AS b ON a.Business_ID = b. Business_ID
GROUP BY a. Business_ID,  a.Income_Desc WITH ROLLUP
```

The result I'm getting is this

```
Business_ID Income Description  Income Amount   Expenditure Amount  Total
1           Income A            1000            2500                 -1500
1           Income B            3000            2500                 500
1           Income C            2000            2500                 -500
1           All Amounts         6000            7500                 -1500
            All Amounts         6000            7500                 -1500
```

Is it possible to get an output like the one I provided above? Could you show me how to achieve it (or something very close) please?

Thanks

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Your data model has some problems, because it is not clear to which income record the single record expenditure amount corresponds.  Rather than trying to put together a query, you might want to refactor your table design.

Comment: Hi, it is 10.3.14-MariaDB-log

Comment: @assetman tagging as mysql may attract answers which might not be appropriate for mariadb as the two are different in terms of the features available and are developing at different pace.

Comment: @P.Salmon, thanks for the advice. I'll look to remove the MySQL tag if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` for the `join`:

```
with ie as (
      select i.business_id, i.income_desc, i.income_amount,
             e.expen_amount
      from (select i.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by business_id order by income_desc) as seqnum
            from income i
           ) i left join
           (select e.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by business_id order by expen_amount) as seqnum
            from expenditure e
           ) e
           on i.business_id = e.business_id and i.seqnum = e.seqnum
       )
select ie.*
from ie
union all
select business_id, 'Total', sum(income_amount), sum(expen_amount)
from ie
group by business_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with that function so I'll need to do a bit of reading on it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a sub query out of your original query and only select values where the business ID is not null. Furthermore, use `CASE WHEN` to identify those values < 0 and replace it with "-":

```
SELECT x.Business_ID
     , x.`Income Description`
     , x.`Income Amount`
     , x.`Expenditure Amount`
     , x.Total
FROM
(SELECT a. Business_ID
     , COALESCE (a.Income_Desc, 'All Amounts') AS 'Income Description'
     , SUM(a.Income_Amount) AS 'Income Amount'
     , SUM(b.Expen_Amount) AS 'Expenditure Amount'
     , CASE WHEN (sum(a.Income_Amount)-SUM(b.Expen_Amount)) < 0
       THEN '-'
       ELSE (sum(a.Income_Amount)-SUM(b.Expen_Amount))
       END AS 'Total'
FROM Income AS a 
    LEFT JOIN Expenditure AS b ON a.Business_ID = b.Business_ID
WHERE a.Business_ID is not null and b.Business_ID is not null
GROUP BY a.Business_ID, a.Income_Desc WITH ROLLUP) as x
where x.Business_ID is not null
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c4ido4nPAXNMHo8mBRe15k/0)

Comment: Waka, thanks for the reply and providing the Fiddle link. I like the use of CASE WHEN. When I executed the query in Fiddle the result gives an expenditure total of 7500. Is it possible to report just the single expenditure figure of 2500 as the total against All Amounts?